# why all records are not fetched from select query?

Tags: php, sql

code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT stop_id FROM routes WHERE busNumber= '" . $busNumber."'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            echo $result->num_rows."records fetched"."<br>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $stop_id = $row["stop_id"];
                //break;
                $sql = "SELECT stop_name FROM stops WHERE stop_id = '" . $stop_id."'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        
                if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $stop = $row["stop_name"];
                        echo "stop is->".$stop."<br>";
                        $result_stops .= $stop;
                        $result_stops .= ";";
                        //break;
                    }
                } 
            }
            echo "stops are". $result_stops. "<br>";
        }
       


echo "end". "<br>";
```

result:

```
3 records fetched<br>stop is->PATIA<br>stops arePATIA;<br>end<br>
```

here 3 records are fetched from select query
but, in while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()); the loop is not running and instead of 3 records, only 1 record is showing that is PATIA. Why others are not showing?

Comment: You're using the same row/result variables for your outer recordset (that would contain all of the stops), and also for the inner recordset.  So when you run your second query (which just gets a single row containing the name of the stop), you've replaced the original $result (that had 3 rows) with a new recordset that only has 1 row.  So then the outer "while" loop also stops, because there are no more rows to fetch from $result.  I'd suggest you use a different variable for the inner "row" and "result"

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: change the cursor name for the second cursor.  you have two while loops and one cursor variable name.  I am surprised this works at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chinpin, this should resolve your issue.  As I commented, you're overwriting variables that you're using in your outer "while" loop with different results.

```
 $sql = "SELECT stop_id FROM routes WHERE busNumber= '" . $busNumber."'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            echo $result->num_rows."records fetched"."<br>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $stop_id = $row["stop_id"];
                //break;
                $sql = "SELECT stop_name FROM stops WHERE stop_id = '" . $stop_id."'";
                $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
                        
                if ($result2->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $stop = $row2["stop_name"];
                        echo "stop is->".$stop."<br>";
                        $result_stops .= $stop;
                        $result_stops .= ";";
                        //break;
                    }
                } 
            }
            echo "stops are". $result_stops. "<br>";
        }
       


echo "end". "<br>";
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod - it's good advice that I would not argue with.

Comment: In my opinion, an answer that does not use parameters -- or even mention them as the correct solution -- should not be upvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm not going to say that I would necessarily disagree with yourself or ServingQuarantineperiod, but for my own understanding (as a new SO contributor) where would you ordinarily expect the line to be drawn between providing a simple answer to the OPs question (in this case, I just provided the same block of code with the obvious re-use of variables remedied) vs "embellishing" with modifications that, yes, could potentially improve the code's structure, but may just confuse a beginning coder?  Comments have been added, which the OP can now investigate further, re SQL injection.